# Email not getting delivered when sender (user's mail) and recipient have same email domain

Tags: email, email-template, approval-process, deliverability

I am testing my approval email templates. When I use "Send Test and Verify Merge Fields" and send the mail to my email account (xxx@testdomain.com) which is also my mail in the org, I don't receive the mail. But If I change it to some other email, for example my gmail, I receive it. Tried this as well using the Test Deliverability and I'm getting the same result. I checked the email logs and the mails are tagged as R/D.

**Case 1**: different email domain - mail getting received

- Sender (User's email): xxx@testdomain.com
- Recipient: zzz@sampledomain.com

**Case 2**: same email domain - NOT getting received

- Sender (User's email): xxx@testdomain.com
- Recipient: zzz@testdomain.com

Comment: Have you tried [testing the email deliverability](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_test_email_delivery.htm&type=5) and taken a look at [troubleshooting for any delivery problems](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212386&type=1)

Comment: Yep, I've tried the scenario above using "Test Deliverability" and I'm receiving the mails when sender and recipient domains are different.